# What is this object?

Tags: music

> originator of yingluck plays this: shush it like a zebra
>
> no wait, it wasn't that, it was the oVer one

Hint 1:

> maybe that should be written "shush (it)": the "it" is describing the "shush".

Hint 2:

> It's nothing too complicated, you don't need to know a lot to work it out. But @f" has left a useful comment which is on the right track.

Comment: [yingluck](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5838)

Comment: @f'' How did you know? :)

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer is

> Piano

shush it

> The term 'piano' is a direction in music indicating that the performer should play softly.

like a zebra

> A zebra has black and white stripes, a piano has black and white keys.

originator of yingluck plays this

> This almost certainly refers to [Yingluck Shinawatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yingluck_Shinawatra) whose originator is Thailand. 
>  One of the traditional instruments of Thailand is a quadruple reed oboe known as the [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_(instrument)). 
>  We'll combine this with the second line below.

no wait, it wasn't that, it was the oVer one

> On first read, this seems like a typo and the sentence should read "the **other** one". 
>  [ANO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._N._Other) is an acronym for A. N. Other, which is used as a placeholder name. 
>  We can combine this from the Pi obtained in the first line to get **Pi + ANO** = Piano

oVer

> The typo here seems purposeful. 
> The **third** and **second** letters of 'other' have been replaced by a V, the Roman numeral for five. 
>  I think this refers to piano tuning on the just intervals, particularly the **perfect fifth** which has a frequency ratio of **3:2** (or perhaps "3 oVer 2").

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right about the answer on the basis of "shush it like a zebra", but that last bit feels like a terrible stretch, not least because a [CENSORED] is not in fact tuned in just intonation.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yeah, I agree with you. It does look like the typo has a purpose, though. I'll try to think of something else.

Comment: Mostly right, but see the added hint and the comment by f".

Comment: So user Doorknob, who apparently originated some "yingluck"-related meme on codegolf.stackexchange.com, uses the name KeyboardFire in some other contexts. Perhaps hexomino's proposed answer is too specific.